# How to make autoplay in this js slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

How can I make the slider autoplay? I'm Using jquery 1.3.2min.js

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  var currentPosition = 0;
  var slideWidth = 560;
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

  // Remove scrollbar in JS
  $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
  slides
    .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
    // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
    .css({
      'float' : 'left',
      'width' : slideWidth
    });

  // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
  $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

  // Insert controls in the DOM
  $('#slideshow')
    .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
    .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');

  // Hide left arrow control on first load
  manageControls(currentPosition);

  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  $('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    });
  });

  // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
  function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically click the element to get things started:

```
$('.control').click();
```

Then set an interval to keep the clicks coming.

```
setInterval(function(){$('.control').click();}, 2000);
```